# unistall sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

[image]

I hope someone can help me . I 've Unistall all components sql server 2005 in the control panel but the configuration tools still there.
I try to open HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > Software > Wow6432Node > Microsoft > Microsoft SQL Server > 90 but did not find it .
how the solution of my problem ?

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: I want to uninstall sql server 2005 , because I have deleted some files in C : \ Program Files \ Microsoft SQL Server inadvertently . then I want to reinstall sql server 2005

Comment: Have you tried to run Setup->Repair?

Comment: yet, how? but I had to uninstall sql server 2005 in the control panel but the configuration tools still there.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will solve your issue but you can try something like this:

```
start /wait <CD or DVD Drive>\setup.exe /qn INSTANCENAME=<InstanceName> REINSTALL=SQL_Engine REBUILDDATABASE=1 SAPWD=<NewStrongPassword>
```

See more at: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259(v=sql.90).aspx